# How to find top corner coordinates of zoomed Image inside ScrollViewer?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have an image inside a ScrollViewer that I zoom from the center using this code (accomplished by setting the RenderTransformOrigin), but regardless of zooming the ScrollViewer's Horizontal/Vertical offsets remain zero.  I'm zooming with a ScaleTransform and that part works great, but the transform doesn't actually modify the image - I think that is the problem.  The ScrollViewer doesn't "know" that the image is scrolled so it doesn't adjust the offsets.

Can I calculate the top left x/y of the viewport considering the scrolling somehow?  Also, I must not understand the offset purpose - given the xaml and my image size of 640x480 (ScrollViewer is 600x480) so the offset should not be zero, should it?

Trying to pass this info into the cropping method.

```
<ScrollViewer  Width="600"  x:Name="ScrollViewerImage" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ZoomMode="Enabled" >
  <CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl" Width="Auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5"  DoubleTapped="PreviewControl_DoubleTapped"  Stretch="Uniform">
    <CaptureElement.RenderTransform >
        <ScaleTransform  x:Name="ZoomScale" />
    </CaptureElement.RenderTransform>
  </CaptureElement>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: you got that right so far, RenderTransform is no LayoutTransform, it only visually transforms the element. Are you missing code in this question? How do you zoom it? ScrollViewer in UWP actually natively supports pinch to zoom and pan, what more do you need?

Comment: To zoom I have a slider and I just update the ZoomScale.{X,Y} from the slider value.  It's a transform so it seems to me that I should be able to apply the transform to the original and get the adjusted values - but that is the part I cannot figure out!    I found a great sample that has cropping code which I wll use to create the file on disk, but the signature requires the startPoint of the crop area (which I think would be the top left of the scroll viewer).   I'm not familiar with LayoutTransform - would that actually resize the image?   I feel like I am making this way too hard!

Comment: ^correction the sliderChanged code is ZoomScale.ScaleX = sliderValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the whole RenderTransform stuff. As I said, the `ScrollViewer` has its own scaling. Take a look at [`ZoomToFactor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomtofactor.aspx). This will get you moving forward. Then you will use the `ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor` and Horizontal and Vertical Offset values and you'll be able to determine your cropping.

Comment: Thanks @Markus!  I have only used ScrollViewer in combination with the image transforms.  I will try without!